# SVN checkout does not recognize url path

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

Trying to download the sound files from the following url: https://github.com/wesbos/JavaScript30/tree/master/01%20-%20JavaScript%20Drum%20Kit/sounds

with TortoiseSVN, however the software says that it does not recognize that url path.

Changed the tree to trunk in the url, tried different directories, however still seeing the same error message.

Received following error message:

```
https://github.com/wesbos/JavaScript30/tree/master/01%20-
%20JavaScript%20Drum%20Kit/sounds doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't even with Github's SVN-bridge checkout subtree of repo (because it's Git anyway) and must get the whole repository. In the case of https://github.com/wesbos/JavaScript30.git repository [for SVN-clients](https://help.github.com/en/articles/support-for-subversion-clients) it will be (AFAICS) `https://github.com/wesbos/JavaScript30` URL